# How to add .aspx page handler on local IIS Set up

Tags: asp.net, iis

Just setting up IIS on my local machine and trying to run a .aspx file entension getting the following error

The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration. If the page is a script, add a handler. If the file should be downloaded, add a MIME map.

Just wondering what I am missing here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you need to run [aspnet_regiis.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h%28v=VS.90%29.aspx). You would pass the -i parameter to update the script maps in the IIS metabase.

Answer (score 2):

In windows XP SP3:

In **Run** type this:

```
cmd
```

in cmd type this:

```
cd C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319
```

you can change installed version of framework

Then type this:

```
aspnet_regiis -i
```